# Nokogiri or "string" to create this HTML fragment?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need to create an HTML fragment to embed in a page (a simple js gallery). This is the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="royalSlider rsDefault">
  <a class="rsImg" data-rsw="632" data-rsh="500" data-rsbigimg="../img/paintings/2.jpg" href="../img/paintings/700x500/2.jpg">
    Vincent van Gogh - The Starry Night
    <img width="96" height="72" class="rsTmb" src="../img/paintings/t/2.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

I can create this using string interpolation, but someone suggest me to use Nokogiri. I do not know how I can nest the nodes.

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse ""
  Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.with(@doc) do |doc|
    g.pictures.each do |picture|
      doc.create_element "a", :class => "rsImg"
    end
  end
```

Is it better to use Nokogiri, or can I also proceed with the easy way (string)? How can I create the nested structure I need?

**Update**

Done with Nokogiri

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse ""
Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.with(@doc) do |doc|
  doc.div(:id => 'content-gallery', :class => 'royalSlider rsDefault') {
    g.pictures.each do |picture|
      doc.a(:src => picture.image_url(:gallery), :class => 'rsImg') {
        doc.img(:src => picture.image_url(:widget), :class => 'rsTmb')
      } 
    end
    }
end
@doc.to_html
```

Comment: Could you tell me what you are trying to do there? Not getting you.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm trying to recreate with nokogiri the HTML fragment... 
g is my gallery object.

I can do with string interpolation, but I want to try Nokogiri.

Comment: You want to produce full `div` and nested `a` fragment..right ?

Comment: I'm trying to create a div and inside the div with an each loop I must insert a lot of a tag with img nested.

Comment: It appears your answer came from [Using Nokogiri HTML Builder to create fragment with multiple root nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906681/using-nokogiri-html-builder-to-create-fragment-with-multiple-root-nodes)