# Convert nokogiri nodeset into original html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have some html code, which i parse, modify. BUt after i use `doc.to_html`
nokogiri converts it back to html, but also appending some extra tags like `doctype, html, head, body`. Is there way to skip these tags, or should i remove them manually?

Comment: Use `DocumentFragment` intead of `Document` :: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4907450/2035262

Comment: @mudasobwa, put it into answer and i accept it. This is what i was looking for

Comment: There are some other ways.. Can you give one example ? Are you applying `#to_html` on Nodes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don’t need to build the whole HTML document, you should use [`DocumentFragment`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907450/2035262) instead of `Document`.